# UIScrollview paging like animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view that have some images, text, and more to show and two button in left and right when user click on left or righr button page should get side and another page should get open with new info.

How i can do it please help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

try with this [link.](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/). You will get the logic to solve your problem. Place a button on each side where you want & use the logic from this thread

Answer (score 1):

Enable paging for the scrollview.

When a button is tapped modify the content offset of the scrollview by the width of the scrollview using setContentOffset:animated:

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
-(IBAction)prevButtonPage:(id) sender 
{ 

    CGFloat xOffset = pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat yOffset = pagingScrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x != pagingScrollView.frame.origin.x)
    {
        [pagingScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xOffset- 320, yOffset) animated:YES];
        // [arrayIndia objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    NSLog(@" custom  x==%f %f", pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x, pagingScrollView.contentSize.width);

}

-(IBAction)nextButtonPage:(id) sender 
{ 

    CGFloat xOffset = pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat yOffset = pagingScrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if ((pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x != pagingScrollView.frame.origin.x)&&(pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x !=[imageArray count]) )
    {
        [pagingScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(xOffset + 320, yOffset) animated:YES];

    }
    NSLog(@" custom  x==%f %f", pagingScrollView.contentOffset.x, pagingScrollView.contentSize.width);

}
```